# Why can't I upload a picture from gallery in my android app, if the picture was taken with the camera app from android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-developer-api

I want to upload an image from gallery and show it on my Android app. This works fine if I select an image from the screenshot folder for example. But when I select an image from the folder where the pics, taken with the phone camera, are stored, it does not work.

```
    public void UploadPicture(View v) {
    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no upload code in the code you posted. And what do you consider to be 'it does not work'?

Comment: Maybe upload is the wrong word. I want to select in my app an image from gallery and show it in an Imageview. The picture is not shown.

Comment: Strange you did not take the time to edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have give run time permission to choose image from gallery and permissions in the manifest.

Use **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** in the manifest also.

Then for opening the gallery use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.PICK");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

In onActivityResult :

```
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {  
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            //Use glide for better result
            Glide.with(this).load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
         }
```

Comment: Permissions and runtime permissions and request legacy external storage are not needed for using ACTION_PICK.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, these problems can be solved by ImagePicker Libraries such as Ucrop.
[Ucrop Library For Android](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop)

Make sure you have Runtime permission Handled. For easier permission handling you can use Dexter
[Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

Make sure u have External Storage Read permission in your manifest file.
You may also require both Read/Write permission if you want to take image from camera.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Note: for android version above Pie paste these attributes in application tag in manifest.xml :

```
<application
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        ... >
...
...
</application>
```