# when i pick image it doesn't appeer

Tags: java, android

Manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

```java
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i,pickImgRQ);
            }
        });

    }
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==pickImgRQ && requestCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(data!=null){
                imageuri=data.getData();
                imageView.setImageURI(imageuri);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why did you remove that other post? I why dont you tell about Pictures directory now?

Comment: ican't understand what post are u talking about

Comment: Sorry. I confused you with the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865376/why-cant-i-upload-a-picture-from-gallery-in-my-android-app-if-the-picture-was?noredirect=1#comment116454190_65865376

Comment: ok. never mind.

Comment: Did you try from the Pictures/Screenshots directory as done there? And you do not need any permission. And certainly not one for write.

Answer (score 0):

use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission in manifest and ask runtime permission on Android 6+(API 23) devices

Comment: i already used it <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> but it doesnot work

Comment: On Android 6+ devices you should ask Runtime permission please read this article
https://www.journaldev.com/10409/android-runtime-permissions-example